# Tensorflow GetConvolveAlgorithms Error

Tags: tensorflow

I'm getting the following error when testing a trained network. 
F c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\kernels\conv_ops.cc:605] Check failed: stream->parent()->GetConvolveAlgorithms(&algorithms)

I have installed CUDA and cudnn correctly. 
python -c "import tensorflow; print(tensorflow.**version**)"

I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\stream_executor\dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library cublas64_80.dll locally
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\stream_executor\dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library cudnn64_5.dll locally
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\stream_executor\dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library cufft64_80.dll locally
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\stream_executor\dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library nvcuda.dll locally
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\stream_executor\dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library curand64_80.dll locally
1.0.1

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] in order to understand the kind of questions that we are expecting. In particular, you haven't provided enough information for us to reproduce the problem. What network have you tried with? Is the source code available? What versions of TensorFlow, CUDA and CuDNN are you using, and on what kind of machine? As it is, possible answers would be pure speculations.